# Suppressing PHP errors with Nginx and php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php5, debian-jessie

Try as I may, I can't suppress error messages from PHP (using php-fpm) being displayed.

Relevant files;

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:display_errors = Off
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:php_flag[display_errors] = off
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:php_admin_flag[display_errors] = off
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:display_errors = Off
```

When I call `phpinfo()` the output is as follows [images as links as this is my first post and therefore don't have sufficient reputation to put them inline, sorry!];

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ttGt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LAah.png

The above shows the Configuration File Path as `/etc/php5/fpm` and the Loaded Configuration File as `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`. The second image shows `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` as `Off`.

Which suggests that these settings have been correctly set, but loading a page with errors results in pages of errors e.g;

> **Unknown**: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in **/path/to/file.php** on line **651****Unknown**: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in **/path/to/file.php** on line **651**

(formatted as above, so the HTML formatting is being applied)

I've also tried setting `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` and even `error_reporting(0);` to no avail.

Also, edited to add;

```
# php5-fpm -i | grep error
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => /var/log/php_err.log => /var/log/php_err.log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => On => On
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
```

What am I missing?

Versions are as follows;

Debian 8 Jessie

PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1

Nginx 1.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Is this plain PHP or do you run code with some kind of framework?

It is rather common for recent frameworks to reconfigure error reporting on the fly and/or registering a custom error handler, so maybe something in your program reconfigures it again?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, It affects both an online store running OpenCart (which may use a variety of frameworks), but also a really simple test script I threw together.

Comment: Also, having greped through the entire code base with `grep -R "display_err" *` there's no reference to anything that would seem to override it :/

(and it was fine on Apache before)